# Javascript - novice script not working

Tags: javascript, html

could someone explain why this script isn't working? I tried to figure it out for long time, but I didn't manage to do it.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function Xyz() {
            var x = 0;
        }

        function Switch() {
            if (x == 0) {
                document.body.style.backgroundColor = "black";
                x = 1;
            }
            else {
                document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
                x = 0;
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button type="button" onclick="Switch()">Click me</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Who is `x` in your function ?

Comment: In what way is it not working? What error messages are reported in your JavaScript console ('F12' usually)? What did you expect it to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> if(x==0)
> ```

Since `x` doesn't exist, it throws a ReferenceError here and aborts the rest of the function.

You need to declare `x` first.

---

This:

> ```
> function Xyz()
> {
>  var x=0;
> }
> ```

- Creates a variable `x` that is **local** to the function *and*
- Is never called anyway

Answer (score 0):

You need to define variable x. I used hoisting in this example.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function Xyz()
{
 var x=0;
}

function Switch()
{
if(x==0)
{
document.body.style.backgroundColor="black";
x=1;
}
else
{
document.body.style.backgroundColor="white";
x=0;
}
}
  var x;
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button type="button"onclick="Switch()">Click me</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue is You need to declare a variable before using it.

```
function Switch()
{
if(x==0) // this x is not defined. 
{
document.body.style.backgroundColor="black";
x=1;
}
else
{
document.body.style.backgroundColor="white";
x=0;
}
}
```

Since you need to use the same variable to update it with each click , define it outside function.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
var x = 0;
function Xyz()
{
 var x=0;
}

function Switch()
{
if(x==0)
{
document.body.style.backgroundColor="black";
x=1;
}
else
{
document.body.style.backgroundColor="white";
x=0;
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button type="button"onclick="Switch()">Click me</button>

</body>
</html>
```